# How to reward android user when he install particular external app inside google play

Tags: android

I need to promote new android app inside an already existing app, so what I want to do is to reward the user when he installs the new app.

I need to know what is the event that should I catch when the user has done installing the new app.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register a BroadcastReceiver to listen package events. See below code only listening package added events.

In the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="PackageAddedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
    <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and your BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class PackageAddedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
       String packagename = intent.getData().getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();
       Log.d(TAG, "Action: " + intent.getAction());
       Log.d(TAG, "The packagename: " + packagename);
       //TODO check if the desired app is installed with the packagename 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check on app start (or whenever you need) if the user contains an specific app by getting an instance of the [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class and getting your other app's package info.

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, PackageManager packageManager) {
    try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If the package is not found then an error would be produced, thats why we need the catch it. and in your case we will return false so you know the user does not have the app installed.

The use of this method would be:

```
  PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
  boolean isInstalled = isPackageInstalled("com.your.otherapp.package.name", packageManager);
```

If that method returns true you can apply whatever you define as a reward in your application.